# _AppStart.cshtml, PackageManager, WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I thouht it would be a simple thing to add SimpleMembersihp to an MVC4 web.  Not so.  The templated code (e.g. C#) is well-suited to supporting it, but web.config is mostly agnostic-- devoid of elements that would configure any particular security mechanism. I was following Scott Allen's MVC4 tutorial on Pluralsight-- that mixed aspnet-Membership with EF stuff. Maybe I missed something, but C# membership-classes were not interacting with aspnet-Membership, they were doing SimpleMembership. So, I removed aspnet-Membership, but now I cannot get PackageManager to 'update-database'.  It complains "You must call the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method...".  So, I added an _AppStart.cshtml file with the call, but PM seems unaware.
_AppStart.cshtml:

```
@using WebMatrix.WebData;
@{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
}
```

Web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
     <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>


    <membership defaultProvider="simple">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership
```

Configuration.cs:

```
protected override void Seed(eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb context)
{
    context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(d => d.Name,
      new Department() { Name = "Engineering" },
      new Department() { Name = "Sales" },
      new Department() { Name = "Shipping" },
      new Department() { Name = "Human Resources" }
      );

    SimpleRoleProvider roles = new WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider();
    SimpleMembershipProvider membership = new SimpleMembershipProvider();
    if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
    {
        roles.CreateRole("Admin");
    }

    //if (membership.GetUser("ej", false) == null)
    //{
        //    membership.CreateUserAndAccount("ej", "FluffyBunny@1", false);
        //    string[] u = { "ej" };
        //    string[] r = { "Admin" };
        //    roles.AddUsersToRoles(u, r);
        //}
}
```

The role "Admin" is not created.?

Comment: Please generalize your code samples and pinpoint what the actual problem you are having is.

Comment: Where in your project tree added the file? I added it to the root of the web app and it worked for me. Regards

Answer (score 11):

Try adding the code

`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);`

To your Application_Start in `global.asax.cs`

`_appStart.cshtml` is not used in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Possible  use  _AppStart.cshtml In MVC4 
By create new file and put it in root Folder

```
@{
 // Initialize WebMail helper
 WebMail.SmtpServer = "your-SMTP-host";
 WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
 WebMail.UserName = "your-user-name-here";
 WebMail.Password = "your-account-password";
 WebMail.From = "your-email-address-here";
 }
```

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior#configuring_email_settings